# Only run selenium test if previous selenium test fails

Tags: ruby, error-handling, selenium

I have several 'it' blocks in my selenium test file *(using Ruby and rspec)* that test various portions of my web application. Each 'it' block stops executing and goes to the next 'it' block if any of the conditions or code fails.

- Is there a way to run an 'it' block
  only if the previous fails or call a
  function to react to the failed test?
- Is there a better way to accomplish what I am wanting to do that doesn't involve an 'it' block?

Example 'it' block

```
it "should load example.com" do
  page.open("http://example.com")
  page.wait_for_page_to_load(25)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like my current solution and think there is a better way to accomplish this, but for now...

- wrap original test code that was in the 'it' block in a begin rescue block
- put code to respond to failure in the rescue section

.

```
it "should load example.com" do
  begin
    page.open("http://example.com")
    page.wait_for_page_to_load(25)
    "wow".should == "cool"
  rescue Exception => e
    // code that responds to failed test
  end
end
```

Why I don't like this

- I feel dirty writing test code like this (it feels wrong!)
- The rspec reports a pass unless the rescue code also fails

Comment: Is this an actual test, or just setup for a later test? Ideally your tests can run in any order, with setup, test, and teardown in one self-contained unit. As far as the test passing, you should probably end the rescue section with something like 'raise "This Test Failed"'.